# JSON.stringify ignores nested object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently working on an issue sending JSON data to My Controller.

I found out that when Passing an Object, which Contains a nested one, the nested object will be null. I can't figure out what I'm missing...

My serverside looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ApplyChanges(List<Change> pChanges)
{
    //the Issue occurs here in every object of pChanges:
    //IgnoreFlag was populated correctly, but the Detection Object is null...?
}

public class Change
{
  public Detection Detection { get; set; }
  public bool IgnoreFlag { get; set; }
}
```

My Clientside looks like this:

```
var data = [
  {
    "Detection": {
     "PropertyOld": 1,
     "PropertyNew": 2, 
    },
    "IgnoreFlag": true
  },
  {
    "Detection": {
     "PropertyOld": 3,
     "PropertyNew": 4, 
    },
    "IgnoreFlag": false
  }
]

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/Url/To/ApplyChanges",
  data: JSON.stringify({"pChanges": data}),
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    //do something here
});
```

Can someone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: try to not stringify, just pass as it is

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried it, but it doesn't work. Same result..

Comment: Nothing is ignored when I `JSON.stringify` your object. https://jsfiddle.net/qz3vp6gx/

Comment: @squint yes, I validated the json string myself on jslint.com before posting this question. Indeed, the JSON string is valid. That's exactly what I find weird about that issue... No Idea, what the reason that my mvc-controller ignores the nested object could be?

Comment: But you're saying that `JSON.stringify` is ignoring something. I'm just showing that it doesn't ignore anything. Based on the client-side code you provided, there's nothing wrong. Not sure what the server-side issue may be.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
JSON.stringify(data)
```

instead of using

```
JSON.stringify({"pChanges": data})
```